# Android XML Layout works in landscape but not in normal orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob, landscape

I'm trying to display an `Admob` ad but this only works in Landscape but not in normal mode.

`layout-land/main.xml` and `layout/main.xml` are the same! (well now they are because i deleted everything else to find the bug)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/test.testpkg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding = "10dip" >

        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
            myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem? An exception, unexpected behaviour, problems with the layout...

Comment: no exception, just the admob ap isnt displayed in portrait orientation.. only in landscape I can see it

Comment: Please try to set android:background="#ff0000" at your AdView to be sure, that the AdView itself gets shown or not. If you you see a red area, the code of the AdView may have problems with the positioning of its content in the portrait aspect view.

Comment: Portrait: http://public.slay.it/MARTIN-PC/634263270466728121.png
Landscape: http://public.slay.it/MARTIN-PC/634263269834261946.png

Comment: Ok the AdView gets displayed in both directions. The layout description seems to be right. I think, there must be something wrong with the code of the view. How do you calculate the positioning of the content of the AdView? Maybe you should debug your draw method. Maybe you have the wrong bounds and therefore the wrong midpoint and places the banner outside ...

Comment: I dont calculate this. This is a component of the AdMob Libary. I think I just open a new Project tomorrow and try it out again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding from your Relative Layout. AdMob doesn't play nice when an ancestor View is padded.

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/test.testpkg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >


 <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/ad" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
 myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
 myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```