# AdMob AdView only appearing in landscape orientation

Tags: android, orientation, admob, adview

Ok, I'm officially at my wit's end here.  Working on an Android app that uses AdMob.  Everything is set up to the letter following [their instructions](http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf), no errors, etc.

Problem is:  I only see ads when the phone is in landscape orientation.

I've searched online and done every last thing I can think of to test this:

- Tried it in test mode and normal mode
- Removed the orientation configChanges from my main activity's manifest and their handlers in the code, in case they were causing it
- Removed all functionality of the app so that onCreate looked like the one in the instructions above
- Tried every possible change of main layout - placing it in different locations, removing other widgets, different layouts, etc

These are just a summary of a few hours of testing, every time the result is the same.  Portrait shows no ad, landscape shows the ad (as/where expected - not stretched, but the max width issue is well known and not a problem).

Logcat shows everything to be working properly in both orientations:  Requests are made, ads are returned.  I can click on the ads that appear in landscape, but tapping the area they're meant to be in portrait does nothing.

It's driving me mental!  Any ideas?

**Edit:  Okay, the problem is gone but I'm afraid I can't really call it a "fix".**  I remembered ads working fine in a previous but similar app.  It was using a different version of the AdMob SDK - I don't know any details, but admob-sdk-android.jar is 77kb rather than 136kb.

I copied the 77kb one from the old app into the new app, along with the attrs.xml file, which necessitated changing the primaryTextColor attribute in the AdView to textColor, and that's it.  Works perfectly now - and as a bonus, the ads stretch horizontally across the whole screen in landscape view as well!

I'm posting this as an edit rather than an answer since it seems more appropriate and I'd still love to know if anyone can shed some light on the issue.  Was it an AdMob SDK issue?

Comment: Have you tried to replace your adview with something static to see if the problem is in layout or in admob integration?

Comment: I tried that and it appeared fine... I also tried giving it fixed width/height, wrapping it in other static layouts, background colours, etc...  Have just edited the question though - problem gone!

Comment: the best answer for ur "problem" can be found here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281349/android-xml-layout-works-in-landscape-but-not-in-normal-orientation

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue, you should check if the parent container is padded, if it is, remove padding and all of sudden ads will appear. I don't find it very logical but it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but i had a similar issue, where in a landscape game, the ads would appear in portrait mode only. On a tab 2 i borrowed for testing from someone. Turned out there was some sort of screen lock on the device which caused it. Spent hours trying to chase the bug down.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".AddTest"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" 
        >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have same problem in tools:ignore = "aaaaaaaaa" and padding